# How connect to Router in eNSP from CentOS?

Tags: centos7, static-routes

I have eNSP installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. On eNSP there is Router, connected through cloud to this host's machine adapter (VirtualBox or LAN). I need to get connection to this Router from another machine with CentOS 7 and vice versa. CentOS's machine in the same network as Windows machine (they are pinging each other). The Router is also available to ping Windows adapter to which it's connected through Cloud. To do this i tried to configure Route Table on Windows and CentOS, but it doesn't help. What I've done: 1) set for Windows route which connects CentOS's IP through LAN interface executing

```
route add <CentOS_IP> mask 255.255.255.0 <Windows_IP>
```

2) set for CentOS route which connects Router's IP through eth0 executing

```
ip route add <Router_IP>/24 via <CentOS_IP>
```

But still it's not pinging from Router to CentOS and conversely. At CentOS I also tried to configure same route (gateway) in /etc/sysconfig/static-routes or /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0 files, but it doesn't help.

File: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0

```
GATEWAY0=<Windows_IP>
NETMASK0=255.255.255.0
ADDRESS0=<Router_IP>
```

File: /etc/sysconfig/static-routes

```
any net <Router_IP> netmask 255.255.255.0 gw <Windows_IP> eth0
```

Even traceroute don't show the first hop. I'll be grateful if someone tell me what I do wrong.